# Does Laravel Authentication accept nullable columns?

Tags: database, laravel

I've been working for at least a month with Laravel and come across a problem.

I have a column that needs to be unique because it's used to log into the site. But I have to have a way to remove a user's personal information to conform with GDPR.

Because things that are relevant to accounting i.e. purchases need to be recorded to conform with other laws, I need to have that user's ID remain so I can store the purchases and sales (in numeric form) to provide to auditors if the situation arises.

The solution I came up with is making the unique column that contains personal information nullable. What would this likely mean when I log in?

For security reasons Laravel doesn't show me what happens when login is called.

Comment: Well, you can use the tables as you want, why not.

Comment: If you want to know what happen when login is called, Try to install barryvdh, https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper